# How to display latest inserted records?

Tags: sql

I want to display the latest inserted records in `gridview`.

**Sample DB:**

```
Id  Alerts   Alert_Date
--  ------   ----------
1   Alert1   5/11/2015 12:12:22 PM
2   Alert2   5/11/2015 12:12:22 PM
3   Alert1   5/12/2015 12:12:22 PM
4   Alert2   5/13/2015 12:12:22 PM
5   Alert2   5/14/2015 12:12:22 PM
6   Alert3   5/14/2015 12:12:22 PM
```

**Expected output:**

```
Alerts    Alert_Date
------    ----
Alert1    5/12/2015 12:12:22 PM
Alert2    5/14/2015 12:12:22 PM
Alert3    5/14/2015 12:12:22 PM
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Alerts,
(SELECT TOP (1) tbl_Notifications.Alert_Date AS Expr1) AS Expr1
FROM tbl_Notifications
```

I tried something that is given above, but it is not working. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (TOP is product specific SQL.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `GROUP BY` clause with `MAX` function as below

```
SELECT Alerts, MAX(Alert_Date)
FROM tbl_Notifications
GROUP BY Alerts
```

Comment: Sometimes simple answers are the best :-))

Comment: @dnoeth hehe that's true - you know it :) even more than sometimes :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP (1) Alert,Alert_Date AS Expr1 
FROM tbl_Notifications order by alert_date desc
```

Comment: Please inform us which dbms your answer is for!. (TOP is product specific SQL, and no dbms is specified.)